# RxJs forkJoin: Execute when all observables have errored or succeeded

Tags: typescript, rxjs, rxjs6

Imagine I have the following code, where one observable throws error and another one succeeds after a delay:

```
let observables: Observable<String>[] = [
  of("string 1").pipe(delay(1000)),
  throwError("error")
];

observables.forEach((observable, i) => {
  observable.subscribe(val => {
    console.log('success ' + i);
  }, error => {
    console.log('error ' + i);
  })
})

forkJoin(observables).subscribe(res => {
  console.log('final success');
}, error => {
  console.log('final error');
});
```

This code will log the following:

```
error 1
final error
success 0
```

What kind of operator or callback could I use in order to execute some code *after* all observables have either succeeded or errored? The goal is to log in this order:

```
error 1
success 0
final error
```

Another acceptable outcome would be to catch the error somewhere, and log:

```
error 1
success 0
final success
```

I made a demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-myfstw?file=index.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a way is to catch the error and to close the stream.

instead of `throwError("error")` to attach pipe to it `throwError("error").pipe(catchError(() => EMPTY))`, then streams with errors simply complete without an error / value. if you want a value, replace `EMPTY` with `of('valueYouWant')`.

It is important to catch the error in the original stream, not in the `pipe` after `forkJoin`.

to automate the catchError you could do

```js
let observables: Observable<String>[] = [
  of("string 1").pipe(delay(1000)),
  throwError("error")
].map(obs => obs.pipe(catchError(() => EMPTY)));
```

Comment: Thanks, but if I return EMPTY in catchError, the second observable will never complete. My code just logs "success 0"

Comment: it does complete but without any emits. NEVER doesn't emit and doesn't complete. If you need to rely on the data - then yes `of(null)` is the right way.

Comment: Yes, I need to run a function when all of the individual observables have either succeeded or failed. That works with of(null). Thank you.